# Average hours getting truncated despite using float in cs50 hours practice problem

Tags: c, floating-point, cs50

In cs5's week 2 hours practice problem, the code correctly gives the total hours spent, but it truncates the average hours per week despite using float. Where am I going wrong?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float calc_hours(int hours[], int weeks, char output);

int main(void)
{
    int weeks = get_int("Number of weeks taking CS50: ");
    int hours[weeks];

    for (int i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
    {
        hours[i] = get_int("Week %i HW Hours: ", i);
    }

    char output;
    do
    {
        output = toupper(get_char("Enter T for total hours, A for average hours per week: "));
    }
    while (output != 'T' && output != 'A');

    printf("%.1f hours\n", calc_hours(hours, weeks, output));
}

// TODO: complete the calc_hours function
float calc_hours(int hours[], int weeks, char output)
{
 int tot = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
    {
            tot = hours[i] + tot;
    }

    if (output == 'T')
    {
        return (float) tot;
    }
    return (float) (tot / weeks);
}
```

I typed in the weeks and hours spent per week when prompted and typed in A to get average of hours spent per week, but it only outputs an integer value instead of a float.

Comment: `tot / weeks` performs _integer_ division, the result of which you then cast to `float`.

Comment: `return (float) tot / weeks;` You need to cast one of the operands, not the result after the integer division has already happened.

Comment: Or, change: `int tot = 0;` to `float tot = 0;`, and get rid of the dangerous casting... (Does CS50 library have `get_float()`? Did you ever invest 8.5 hrs during one week?

Comment: Retired Ninja is right, and changing tot to float worked @Fe2O3 ! Yes using get_float would make sense but I'm not supposed to edit the main function for this problem.

Comment: Bonus points for not using `else` in your function! Earn more by figuring out how to have only one `return` statement in that function... (Hint: `tot` is a local variable that can be made to serve your purposes...)

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

> ```
> (float) (tot / weeks)
> ```

"*Where am I going wrong?*" As noted, integer division (with truncation) is occurring within the parentheses, before the quotient is *cast* to `float`.

The simplest solution is to define the variable that will be returned from the `float` function to be a `float` itself:

```
float calc_hours( int hours[], int weeks, char output ) {
    float tot = 0.0;

    for( int i = 0; i < weeks; i++ )
        tot += hours[ i ];

    if( output == 'T' )
        return tot; // no casting required

    if( weeks == 0 ) {
        printf( "Division by zero is not defined\n" );
        return -1; // something. Maybe sqrt( -1 );  :-)
    }

    return tot / weeks; // will be 'float' calculation, not integer
}
```

May as well learn the *gotcha* now and try to avoid having it bite you later.

**EDIT**
Just thought! A `float` is limited to ~7 digits of precision, while a 32bit `int` ranges up to just above 9 digits. If `tot` is expected to be greater than `999,999`, this function may not produce accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, you are casting the result of integer division to `float`.

> ```
> (float) (tot / weeks)
> ```

You need to cast one of the operands to `/` to `float` *first* to perform floating point math.

```
(float)tot / weeks
```

Answer (score 0):

- As mentioned by others, code is doing an integer division with an integer quotient.  To achieve a floating point quotient, use floating-point math.
- Also, avoid overflow when adding up the integer values.
- Using integer math to perform the summation is good and efficient.  Using a `float` sum readily risks rounding issues if used to sum the `int`s when `hours[]` is large.
- In C, consider `double` for typical floating-point math and save `float` for select cases where the limited precision and range are specifically needed.  Note that `printf("%.1f hours\n", calc_hours(hours, weeks, output));` converts the `float` return value from `calc_hours()` to `double` before passing the argument to the `printf(...)` function.

```
// Alternative
double calc_hours(const int hours[], int weeks, char output) {
  long tot = 0; // or long long tot
  for (int i = 0; i < weeks; i++) {
    tot = hours[i] + tot;
  }

  if (output == 'T') {
    return (double) tot;
  }
  return (double) tot / weeks;
}
```

- Advanced: use `size_t` for array sizing.

```
double calc_hours(const int hours[], size_t weeks, char output) {
```